# Auto update MySql field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 mysql tables and I want that:

1) when I delete an article, the associated tags to be automatically deleted

2) when I add/delete a tag, the "hasTags" field from the articles to be auto updated (0 - for 0 tags, 1 - for 1+ tags).

For 1 - I used a foreign key and it works

```
ALTER TABLE `articles`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `articles_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I don't know how to do for the second part. It is possible?

The tables are

```
articles == id | title | content | hasTags

tags == id | articleId | tagname
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need to write a stored procedure ( better ) or a trigger.

Comment: Odd table structure. So each Tag can only have one article? Why not have a join table so each tag can be applied to many articles and and each article can have many tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For part 2 you can either do this on your application code, in the part where you also add/delete a tag.

Update, I would suggest making `hastags` a reference counter, that way you avoid the problem @James mentioned.

Or you can create 3 triggers:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ai_tags_each AFTER INSERT ON tags FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE articles SET hasTags = COALESCE(hastags,0) + 1 WHERE id = NEW.article_id;
END $$

CREATE TRIGGER ad_tags_each AFTER DELETE ON tags FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE articles SET hasTags = hasTags - 1 WHERE id = OLD.article_id;
END $$

CREATE TRIGGER au_tags_each AFTER UPDATE ON tags FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE articles SET hasTags = hasTags - 1 WHERE id = OLD.article_id;
  UPDATE articles SET hasTags = COALESCE(hastags,0) + 1 WHERE id = NEW.article_id;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: if an article has 2 tags then your 2nd trigger will wrongly set hasTags to 0 if one of them is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

For part 1, you have defined the `FOREIGN KEY` the opposite way. You need:

```
ALTER TABLE tags
  ADD CONSTRAINT articles_tags_FK
        FOREIGN KEY (articleId) 
          REFERENCES articles (id) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

---

For part 2, do you really need the `hasTags` column?

You can drop it and use:

```
SELECT a.id
     , a.title
     , a.content
     , EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tags WHERE articleId = a.id)
       AS hasTags
FROM articles AS a
```